# Commit offset in Reactor Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I have a reactor Kafka project that consumes messages from Kafka topic, transforms the message and then writes to another topic.

```
public Flux<String> consume(String destTopic) {
        return kafkaConsumerTemplate
                .receiveAutoAck()
                .doOnNext(consumerRecord -> log.info("received key={}, value={} from topic={}, offset={}",
                        consumerRecord.key(),
                        consumerRecord.value(),
                        consumerRecord.topic(),
                        consumerRecord.offset())
                )
                .doOnNext(s-> sendToKafka(s,destTopic))
                .map(ConsumerRecord::value)
                .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while consuming : {}", throwable.getMessage()));
    }
```

My understanding is the offset is committed only after all the sequence steps are completed successfully in reactor. Is that correct? I want to make sure the next record is not processed unless the current record is successfully sent to the destination Kafka Topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is like this:

```
@Override
public Flux<Flux<ConsumerRecord<K, V>>> receiveAutoAck(Integer prefetch) {
    return withHandler(AckMode.AUTO_ACK, (scheduler, handler) -> handler
        .receive()
        .filter(it -> !it.isEmpty())
        .publishOn(scheduler, preparePublishOnQueueSize(prefetch))
        .map(consumerRecords -> Flux.fromIterable(consumerRecords)
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> {
                for (ConsumerRecord<K, V> r : consumerRecords) {
                    handler.acknowledge(r);
                }
            })));
}
```

So, every `ConsumerRecords` is ack'ed only when its `Flux` is fully processed: successfully or with an error. Therefore it is not a commit-per-record. And technically it must not be per record anyway, since we need a commit only our consumer app fails and we need to continue from the offset we have left before. The currently active `KafkaConsumer` keeps a cursor in-memory and doesn't care if you commit or not.

If you really want "per record" see `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.receive()` and its `KafkaReceiver.receive()` delegate:

```
/**
 * Starts a Kafka consumer that consumes records from the subscriptions or partition
 * assignments configured for this receiver. Records are consumed from Kafka and delivered
 * on the returned Flux when requests are made on the Flux. The Kafka consumer is closed
 * when the returned Flux terminates.
 * <p>
 * Every record must be acknowledged using {@link ReceiverOffset#acknowledge()} in order
 * to commit the offset corresponding to the record. Acknowledged records are committed
 * based on the configured commit interval and commit batch size in {@link ReceiverOptions}.
 * Records may also be committed manually using {@link ReceiverOffset#commit()}.
 *
 * @return Flux of inbound receiver records that are committed only after acknowledgement
 */
default Flux<ReceiverRecord<K, V>> receive() {
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Artem Bilan. So if I am understanding correctly, in my code receiveAutoAck will receive a flux containing batch of consumer records, the consumer records will be committed when its entire flux is processed ie, after sendtoKafka is processed and if it is successful or not. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Independently if that `sendtoKafka()` is successful or not. For pipe-line use-case like receive-n-send consider to use a `receiveExactlyOnce()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control commit behavior you need to disable auto commit like this:

```java
ReceiverOptions.create()
    .commitInterval(Duration.ZERO)             
    .commitBatchSize(0)
```

Then you need to commit once the record have been processed:

```java
final ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create()
                .commitInterval(Duration.ZERO)
                .commitBatchSize(0)
                .subscription(List.of("mytopic"));
sender.send(KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
                        .receive()
                        .map(m -> SenderRecord.create(transform(m.key(), m.value()), m.receiverOffset()))) // transform the data
                .doOnNext(m -> m.correlationMetadata().commit().block()); // Synchronous commit after record is successfully delivered
```